# Linked list using the c++ approach of classes

Tags: c++, class, linked-list

The problem is that while adding data in the linked list its fine but when we search something from the list it says the list is empty 
But if I initialize this

```
struct student * head = NULL;
struct student * curr = NULL;
```

outside the class then it works fine is my approach correct or we can not do it this way?

```
#include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    struct student{
    int data = -100;
    student * next;
    };

    class linkedlist{
     struct student * head = NULL;
     struct student * curr = NULL;

    public:
    void insertitem()
    {
       if(head == NULL){
       struct student * temp = new student;
       head = temp;
       curr = temp;
       temp->next = NULL;
       cout << "Enter the data" << endl;
       cin >> temp->data;
    }
       else if(head != NULL){
           struct student * temp = new student;
           curr->next = temp;
           curr = temp;
           temp->next = NULL;
           cout << "Enter the data" << endl;
           cin >> temp->data;
       }
    }

    void searchitem(int x)
    {
        student * temp = new student;
        temp = head;
        if(temp != NULL)
        {

         while(temp->data != x)
          {
            temp = temp->next;  //Traversal

            if(temp == NULL){
                break;
             }

          }
        }
        if(temp != NULL)
        {
            cout << "found" << endl;
            cout << temp->data << endl;
        }

        else{
            cout << "Not found" << endl;
        }
    }

    };

    int main()
    {
      int x = -100;

      while(x != 0){
      cout << "--------------------" << endl;
      cout << "Enter 1 -- Insertion" << endl;
      cout << "Enter 0--- Terminate" << endl;
      cout << "--------------------" << endl;
      cin >> x;

      linkedlist l1;

      switch(x)
      {
      case 1:
           l1.insertitem();
        break;
      case 2:
           l1.searchitem(6);
        break;
      }
      }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You are leaking a student in every call of searchitem, and your list can contain at most two elements, trying to insert a third will leak the tail. What are you trying to achieve with this class?

Comment: A useful debugging technique for this is constructor/destructor logging. You will see things constructed and especially destructed when they are not supposed to be. You will see that there are more constructed than destructed.

Comment: In C++, you don't need the `struct` or `class` keyword when declaring variables.  The type name alone will suffice.

Comment: In your `insertitem` function, you don't need the `if` in `else if` because the `else` means `(head != NULL)`.

Comment: In the `insertitem` function, there are duplicate statements.  I recommend you move some before the `if` or after the end of the `else`.  You want to prevent duplicate code because that increases your development time (typing and debugging).

Comment: In your `searchitem` function, there is no need for creating a `new` `student` object.  Initialize a *pointer* to point to the head node, then walk the *pointer* through the list.  Your `insertitem` function is in charge of creating new nodes.  Searching should be passive - not modifying the list.

Comment: In the `main` function, you create a linked list if the User wants to terminate, which is a waste.  Also, you don't tell the user that there is an option #2.

Comment: @Caleth I just wana create a genaric class to create a linked list an to practice all the basic functions on it. What i think is that each time the class object is called in main a new linked list is created due to the initializations od head an curr in the class can it be modified or it needs a whole new approach ?

Comment: Also it was working fine without that class and simple functions so how should we create a class for it if my approach is not right ?

Comment: @Thomas Matthews Yeah got that thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new `linkedlist` on every iteration.

Move the declaration out of the loop.